# How to get all keys values of the player prefs in unity [java script ]

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

in the first test game I've developed if the player passed all the levels and win , he must enter his name ... so his name and his score will be stored in a player prefs :

[image]

there is another scene that displays the names and scores of all the user passed the game :

[image]

I've searched from the morning and try all the ways I know and finally I failed to perform this .... is it possible to display all the keys values previously stored in the player prefs ???

or can someone provide me by a JavaScript to do this ????

thanks...

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create your high score structure the way you want to, serialize it to string using json and save that string in playerprefs

use either of these to serialize

```
http://json.codeplex.com/
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom script called [ArrayPrefs2](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ArrayPrefs2) on the Unity3D Wiki to store arrays of data as a value in a [PlayerPref](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)'s key.

Using this method you don't need to try to figure out how to pull heaps of random PlayerPref key\values. For your case you could have two key->Value pairs as such:

```
HighScoresName  \\ String array
HighScoresValue \\ int array
```